# is it bad practice to use instance variables inside modules?

Tags: ruby

if I want to memoize the result of a method in a module, is that considered bad practice?

imagine I have a rails helper:

```
module FooHelper
  def values_for_thingie
    if some_condition && that_other_condition
      { a: "foo", b: "bar" }
    else
      { a: "bar", b: "baz" }
    end
  end
end
```

Let's assume a rails view is going to call this helper method multiple times ..  one to get the value for "a", and another to get the value of "b"...  Let's also assume that some_condition is a method that does something super complicated so we don't want that to get called more than once...

This can be solved by doing:

```
module FooHelper
  def values_for_thingie
    @values_for_thingie ||= \
      if some_condition && that_other_condition
        { a: "foo", b: "bar" }
      else
        { a: "bar", b: "baz" }
      end
  end
end
```

However, I don't like how this feels because this instance variable has nothing to do with an instance of FooHelper..  It's not really under its control.  And so for that reason, it seems like this is not a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the condition is constant across instances, it should probably be a class/module method. Then, the instance variable used for memoization will be an instance variable for that class/method. Nothing wrong with that. Or, alternatively, you can keep it as an instance method and use a class variable for memoization.

Answer (score 1):

Your instance variable does not live in your module but in the instance of the class the module is included in.

In your example `@values_for_thingie` is defined in FooHelper but will live in an ActionView instance.

So if the result of values_for_thingie must change between requests, you're doing it right.

However you should consider to memoize only the method that take some time to run in your case `some_condition`